# How to save JS objects in array using react native AsyncStorage and display in a Flatlist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, asyncstorage, flatlist

Good day React Native Developers!

I have been trying to implement bookmarking feature in my dictionary app using react native
AsyncStorage but there is a problem. I don't know how to go about it.

The array looks like this:

```html
const [Words, setWords] = useState([
    {name: 'Ab initio', meaning: 'From the beginning.', id: '1' },

    {name: 'A.R.S', meaning: 'Arizona Revised Statutes, Books containing the laws that the Arizona Legislature has enacted.', id: '2' }, 
    
    {name: 'Abandon. ', meaning: 'To intentionally give up a right or property without any plan of reclaiming it in the future; to desert a spouse or child.', id: '3' }, 
    
    {name: 'Abandonment', meaning: 'Giving up a legal right.', id: '4' }, 
    
    {name: 'Abatable nuisance.', meaning: 'A nuisance that can be reduced.', id: '5' },
]);
```

Below is my react native flatlist that displays the list:

```html
<FlatList
    initialNumToRender={70}
          data={filteredDataSource} 
          numColumns={1}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id} 
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
       
            <List >

<ListItem onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Dicpage', item)}>
  <Left>
    <Text numberOfLines={1}  style={{
  fontSize: 18, fontFamily: "Lato-Regular", textTransform: 'capitalize',
  }}>{item.name}</Text>
  </Left>
  
</ListItem>

</List>

       )}

/>
```

Now i want every item to be save in using asycstorage once each item is clicked. I also want to display a list of the bookmarked item in another page.

Please help me with just a sample code. I will be fine with that...

Comment: Anybody Please!

Comment: wait! let writing a answer

Answer (score 1):

To save in AsyncStorage

```
AsyncStorage.setItem("words", JSON.stringify(Words))
```

To get the item from asyncStorage

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('words', (err, result) => {
   if(result) {
      // get the data from storage and save it to the state that you have given in List
      dataSource = JSON.Parse(result) 
   }
});
```

// IF dataSource is not empty then render the Lsit

```
{dataSource && 
<FlatList
    initialNumToRender={70}
          data={dataSource} 
          numColumns={1}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id} 
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
       
            <List >

<ListItem onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Dicpage', item)}>
  <Left>
    <Text numberOfLines={1}  style={{
  fontSize: 18, fontFamily: "Lato-Regular", textTransform: 'capitalize',
  }}>{item.name}</Text>
  </Left>
  
</ListItem>

</List>

}
```

to save a single object on every word on listItem click do this

```
async setFavouriteWords(item) {

// first check if any word is save or not 
let words = await AsyncStorage.getItem("words")

//If words exist, append list with new item object other wise save new object
if(words) {
    words = JSON.parse(words)
    words = [...words, item]
   await  AsyncStorage.setItem("words",JSON.stringify(words));

 } else {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("words",JSON.stringify([item]));
  }
 navigation.navigate('Dicpage', item)
}
```

call this function on click

```
<ListItem onPress={
 async () => {await this.setFavouriteWords(item)
}>
```

Comment: Thank you but this code actually saves all the words in asycstorage. I want to be able to save only the item object in the array.

Comment: Please check the code and see what i am talking about

Comment: you want to save item object, on press .. when you navigate ?

Comment: No! I want to save only one word to aycstorage. For example, in the array above, only one object in the array will be save onclick. Just as we have bookmark features in many dictionary app.

Comment: which one name, meaning or id

Comment: At the end, users should be able to save their favorite word in the list to asycstorage. I also want to be able to display the users favorite words in another list.

Comment: I want to be able to save each of the object:

Comment: I want to be able to save each of the object:

Comment: Do you under what i am describing now?

Comment: I have updated my answer, check if it is helpful. thanks

Comment: Okay! Thank you very much! I will try this out